# The function inside ContinueWith() is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

```
public void Login()
{
    string email = emailInputField.text;
    string password = passwordInputField.text;
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(
        task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("[Login Success] ID: " + auth.CurrentUser.UserId);
                PlayerInformation.auth = auth;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("SongSelectScene");
            }
            else
            {
                messageUI.text = "[Login Failed] Please check your account";
                Debug.Log("[Login Failed] Please check your account");
            }
        });
}
```

I'm a student learning unity.. I've trying to make a sign-up and log-in function in unity by firebase. (using unity 2020.3.20f1)

However, except Debug.Log() function, it doesn't work when I execute it in unity. For the above code, Debug.Log() is working when I input valid email and password but SceneManager.LoadScene() is not working...

I tried to change the value(like messageUI.text = ~~) in the ContinueWith() but it is not working either...
I really need your help...
Thank you.

Comment: does unity have a sync-context? if so, that would explain things; it seems to me that you should really just `await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);` and have the other code *underneath* (and make the login method `public async Task Login()`, obviously, possibly `LoginAsync()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Unity API can only be used on the Unity main thread.

[`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) is **not** guarenteed to be executed on the same thread as the task was started on!

Specifically for this reason Firebase offers the [TaskExtensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) [`ConinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension#class_firebase_1_1_extensions_1_1_task_extension_1af1fc309e7e9b9e9a3655b8b47cb06014) which in the background uses something similar to e.g. [UnityMainThreadDispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher) for dispatching the result callbacks back into the Unity main thread via an internal thread-save [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) and a dedicated `Update` method working it off.

```
public void Login()
{
    string email = emailInputField.text;
    string password = passwordInputField.text;
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWithOnMainThread(
        task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("[Login Success] ID: " + auth.CurrentUser.UserId);
                PlayerInformation.auth = auth;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("SongSelectScene");
            }
            else
            {
                messageUI.text = "[Login Failed] Please check your account";
                Debug.Log("[Login Failed] Please check your account");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to learn the login function by watching a past lecture(2019), so there was different from the previous version... Though there was a lot of ambiguity because it was my first question, thank you again for your kind explanation:D