How can I change the text on a button using a script?
I'm fairly new to Unity and I'm trying to make a script that will change the text of a button from data on firebase. On the canvas I have a Text (TMP) object and four buttons (each with TMP children). My script does pull the data from firebase (I tested with debug statements). I was able to get the Text object on the canvas to update its text based on the data pulled from firebase however the Text children on the buttons do not change even though I use the same method.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;         // ui components
using TMPro;                  // Add the TextMeshPro namespace
using Firebase.Database;      // database operations

public class questionLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI questionText;

    public Button choiceAButton;
    public Button choiceBButton;
    public Button choiceCButton;
    public Button choiceDButton;

    private DatabaseReference dbReference;

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Firebase database reference
        dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        // Load the first question to test
        LoadQuestion("01");
    }

    void LoadQuestion(string questionID)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Loading question with ID: {questionID}");
        dbReference.Child("questions").Child(questionID).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("firebase data not retrieved");
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                if (snapshot.Exists)
                {
                    Debug.Log("IN SNAPSHOT IF STATEMENT");

                    // Set question text
                    string question = snapshot.Child("question").Value.ToString();
                    Debug.Log($"Question: {question}");


                    // Check if choice nodes exist
                    bool choiceAExists = snapshot.Child("choiceA").Value != null;
                    bool choiceBExists = snapshot.Child("choiceB").Value != null;
                    bool choiceCExists = snapshot.Child("choiceC").Value != null;
                    bool choiceDExists = snapshot.Child("choiceD").Value != null;

                    Debug.Log($"Choice A Exists: {choiceAExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice B Exists: {choiceBExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice C Exists: {choiceCExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice D Exists: {choiceDExists}");

                    // Assign database values to strings
                    string choiceA = snapshot.Child("choiceA").Value != null ? snapshot.Child("choiceA").Value.ToString() : "No Choice A";
                    string choiceB = snapshot.Child("choiceB").Value != null ? snapshot.Child("choiceB").Value.ToString() : "No Choice B";
                    string choiceC = snapshot.Child("choiceC").Value != null ? snapshot.Child("choiceC").Value.ToString() : "No Choice C";
                    string choiceD = snapshot.Child("choiceD").Value != null ? snapshot.Child("choiceD").Value.ToString() : "No Choice D";


                    // see if data was successfully stored from database

                    Debug.Log($"Choice A: {choiceA}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice B: {choiceB}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice C: {choiceC}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice D: {choiceD}");

                    // Update question text using TextMeshProUGUI
                    questionText.text = question;
                    choiceAButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = choiceA;
                    choiceBButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = choiceB;
                    choiceCButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = choiceC;
                    choiceDButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = choiceD;
             

                    Debug.Log("Question and choices updated");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("No question data found in Firebase for the ID");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

The debug statements all show proper assignment of values from database. I tried putting a variable to reference the TextMeshProUGUI component of the button as follows:
private TextMeshProUGUI choiceAText;
and inside the LoadQuestion function used this to assign a value like the question text.
choiceAtext.text = choiceA;
but that also did not work.
I tried hardcoding the change to the text child of the button in the start function and that worked to change the text, so I'm assuming the issue is with how I'm accessing the child inside the function.
Any help is appreciated!! Thank you :)

You can replace your debug statements with Debug.Log($"Choice A: {choiceA}", choiceAButton);, so that when you click the log in the console window, Unity will highlight that button for you, this method helps you to make sure if the referenced buttons is correct.

Where have you set choiceAText? Are you sure its a TextMeshUGUI? did you debug what happens?

Have you tried using ContinueWithOnMainThread instead? Most of Unity API can not be used on a background thread/task and you can't be sure where ContinueWith will be running .. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929783/the-function-inside-continuewith-is-not-working

I have manually put in some data and the code works.


Check if you have the button in canvas.

Check, if you have the TMP package installed.

If you did all these things and created the buttons through UI -> Button - Text Mesh Pro; The code will work, otherwise there is a problem with your database, but if you said that the debugs show the right asignment of values, then the problem has to be in creation of the Button gameObject.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;         // ui components
using TMPro;                  // Add the TextMeshPro namespace

public class questionLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI questionText;

    public Button choiceAButton;
    public Button choiceBButton;
    public Button choiceCButton;
    public Button choiceDButton;

    private string[] dbReference;

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Firebase database reference
        dbReference = new string[4];
        dbReference[0] = "A";
        dbReference[1] = "B";
        dbReference[2] = "C";
        dbReference[3] = "D";

        // Load the first question to test
        LoadQuestion("01");
    }

    void LoadQuestion(string questionID)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Loading question with ID: {questionID}");


                    // Set question text
                    string question = "????????";
                    Debug.Log($"Question: {question}");


                    // Check if choice nodes exist
                    bool choiceAExists = dbReference[0] != null;
                    bool choiceBExists = dbReference[1] != null;
                    bool choiceCExists = dbReference[2] != null;
                    bool choiceDExists = dbReference[3] != null;

                    Debug.Log($"Choice A Exists: {choiceAExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice B Exists: {choiceBExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice C Exists: {choiceCExists}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice D Exists: {choiceDExists}");

                    // see the data stored
                    Debug.Log($"Choice A: {dbReference[0]}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice B: {dbReference[1]}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice C: {dbReference[2]}");
                    Debug.Log($"Choice D: {dbReference[3]}");

                    // Update question text using TextMeshProUGUI
                    choiceAButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dbReference[0];
                    choiceBButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dbReference[1];
                    choiceCButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dbReference[2];
                    choiceDButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dbReference[3];


                    Debug.Log("Question and choices updated");
                
    }

}


Pretty sure it is rather a threading issue .. the part you removed to make it work ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929783/the-function-inside-continuewith-is-not-working
